# Flask render select based on a list of tuples

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

I have a data that looks like this that I send from flask render_template

a list of tuples called `product_list`

```
[(22, '1', 'false'), (94, '2', 'true'), (95, '3', 'false'), (100, '4', 'false'), (101, '5', 'false'), (102, '6', 'false'), (103, '7', 'false'), (104, '8', 'false'), (105, '9', 'false'), (106, '10', 'false'), (120, '11', 'false'), (121, '12', 'false')]
```

Essentially

first item in tuple is "product_id", second item is "product_version", third item is "is_product_active"

I am trying to render these tuples in a `select` tag on my html.

The list is ordered in a way such that first item in the list is suppose to be `selected` in the dropdown so I tried this

```
<select size="2" data-width="fit" style="line-height:2px">
    <option value="{{product_list[0][0]}}" selected >Version: {{product_list[0][1]}}</option>
    {% for product in product_list|slice:"1:" %}
          <option value="{{product[0]}}">Version {{product[1]}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This doesn't work, flask jinja throws error saying `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'string'`

Mostly coming from  `product_list|slice:"1:"`

I essentially set the first item of the array as selected, then I am attempting to skip the first item in my array and simply add other items in the dropdown.

What is the cleaner way of doing this such that it also helps in readability of the html code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket notation.

```
{% for product in product_list[1:] %}
```